# Syntax error in INSERT into statement when adding to access database

Tags: vb.net, sql-insert

Someone please help me on finding the error on my code.
the error is at the line inside my try and catch where im trying to add record on  my database Access. the error is "`Syntax error in INSERT into statement`". I already tried using

```
ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
            da.Update(ds, "Users")
```

on my registration for voters and it works fine. idk why it doesnt work on this form (user registration).

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class UserRegister
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String


Private Sub Label4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

End Sub

Private Sub UserRegister_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbProvider = " PROVIDER=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Users\Ronel\Documents\database\CSdatabase.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT*FROM tblUsers"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Users")
    MsgBox("Database now Open")
    con.Close()
    'MsgBox("Database now Close")

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

    Dim empty =
    Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
    If empty.Any Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("PLEASE FILL ALL FIELDS:"))
    Else
        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Users").NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item("Username") = TextBoxUser.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Password") = TextBoxPass.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("LastName") = TextBoxFN.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("GivenName") = TextBoxGN.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("MiddleName") = TextBoxMN.Text

        ' Try
        ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "Users")
        '   Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error updating")
        '  End Try

        ' Me.Dispose()
        'Comelec.Show()
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try `sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers"` ...

Comment: tried this. im still getting the error.

Comment: yes. on my access database i have fields which is to be filled up by admin and not by the users.

Comment: I don't see any INSERT statement...Where is it?

Comment: i didnt use any insert statement on my code. idk why does the error asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems. First, your SQL statement needs some spaces in it. Instead of `sql = "SELECT*FROM tblUsers"`, use `sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers"`.

Second, when using `OleDbCommandBuilder`, the code connects to the database using the `SELECT` statement you provided for the `DataAdapter`, and uses that to generate the necessary SQL for Update, Delete, and Insert statements. The connection to the database needs to be open for this to occur -- you connection is closed at the point where the CommandBuilder is running. This is probably where the syntax error is coming from.

The CommandBuilder will create these statements using **all** of the fields specified in the `SELECT`. If you have fields in your Users table other than the five you are attempting to populate, the `OleDbCommandBuilder` is still going to build an INSERT statement that will attempt to fill those fields as well. Depending on how your table is structured, this may cause rows to be rejected if required fields aren't populated. To take a look at what SQL statements are being generated, you can look at properties of the `DataAdapter` object after using the CommandBuilder:

```
con.Open
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
Debug.Print("SELECT: " & da.SelectCommand.CommandText)
Debug.Print("UPDATE: " & da.UpdateCommand.CommandText)
Debug.Print("DELETE: " & da.DeleteCommand.CommandText)
Debug.Print("INSERT: " & da.InsertCommand.CommandText)
```

Some additional reading on CommandBuilders is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Give this a try:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class UserRegister
    Const dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\Ronel\Documents\database\CSdatabase.mdb"
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    'Specify only the fields you need
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT UserName, Password, LastName, GivenName, MiddleName FROM tblUsers"


    Private Sub UserRegister_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.Open()
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Users")
        ' Get commands now, while connection is open. Do this once when the form is loaded, not every time button is clicked.
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Validation code goes here
        If empty.Any Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("PLEASE FILL ALL FIELDS:"))
        Else
            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
            dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Users").NewRow()
            dsNewRow.Item("Username") = TextBoxUser.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("Password") = TextBoxPass.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("LastName") = TextBoxFN.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("GivenName") = TextBoxGN.Text
            dsNewRow.Item("MiddleName") = TextBoxMN.Text

            Try
                con.Open()
                ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
                da.Update(ds, "Users")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error updating: " & Err.Description)
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```